# Call mdi child methods from parent

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

I have a save button in MDI parent form and I want to call some method in the active MDI child form everytime the user click this button.

Suppose I have the activemdichild.name stored in a variable.

```
string name = this.ActiveMdiChild.Name.ToString();
```

And all my MDI child forms have a save method.

```
public void SaveForm()
{
//Some code here
}
```

How do I programmatically call SaveForm method?

If this aren´t best practices, what do you suggest?

Comment: What is the type of the Mdi forms?

Comment: What do you mean with 'type'? public partial class EmpresasView : Form, IEmpresas ??

Comment: That's what I was looking for.  I'll update my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the type of the MDI Form children is `MyMdiForm` you can do the following

```
foreach (var form in MdiChildren) {
  var view = form as IEmpresas;
  if (view != null) {
    view.SaveForm();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jared, just one question, what is the need to iterate through children if I already known ActiveMdiChild?

Comment: @JorgeZapata i was going off the title of your question. If you just want to save the active one then you could just do the inner body of the loop on the `ActiveMdiChild` value

Answer (score 2):

What about having your child forms implement an interface that defines the kinds of things you expect your mdi children to implement.

Such as:

```
IChildWindow
{
  void Save()
}

public class MyChildClass : IChildWindow
{
  public void Save()
  {
  }
}
```

Then in your mdi parent form:

```
foreach (var child in MdiChildren)
{
  var childAsIWindow = child as IChildWindow;
  if (childAsIWindow == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Not a IChildWindow");
  // or you could just ignore them.

 childAsIWindow.Save();
}
```

Comment: I didn't notice that the forms already implement IEmpresas -- does that interface define the Save method?

Comment: Yes, there is a SaveForm method in IEmpresas